# what is the equivalent of --wrap in windows?

Tags: c, wrapper, icc

what is the equivalent of "Wl,--wrap" compiler option in windows? im using ICC.
for some reason I cant find it any ware.

thanks.

Comment: are you sure there is one?

Comment: This option is an extension of GCC's linker. I don't know if ICC has a similar option, but you will find such information in its documentation. Read it.